# Mysql Creating sort index performance for simple frequent query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, myisam

I'm working on a mysql table with roughly 4 million message entries and I'm trying to select the latest 50 messages based on a timestamp.

An additional requirement is that the returned messages do not start with a fixed prefix.

The problem is that a single query is taking roughly 25% cpu and takes around up to 1.5 seconds. The query is done frequently by multiple clients and is causing performance issues on our 8 core db-server.

```
SELECT * FROM largeTable 
WHERE msg NOT LIKE 'myPrefix%' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
```

I tried profiling with the builtin mysql profiler, here's the result for the query:

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000044 |
| checking permissions | 0.000004 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000010 |
| init                 | 0.000019 |
| System lock          | 0.000005 |
| optimizing           | 0.000005 |
| statistics           | 0.000007 |
| preparing            | 0.000007 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000002 |
| executing            | 0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 0.000006 |
| Creating sort index  | 0.788023 |
| end                  | 0.000009 |
| query end            | 0.000003 |
| closing tables       | 0.000009 |
| freeing items        | 0.000012 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000010 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

I first thought that maybe the problem is that it checks the prefix for all entries but after the profiling .

```
| Creating sort index  | 0.788023 |
```

Seems to be the culprit. So the ORDER BY Clause?
How can i speed this up? 
Is there some type of index i can build to fix this?
New messages are added approximately every few seconds, while queries happen a more often.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Thanks for the comments, here's the info requested.

The database is not being created and filled by my code but by some external python service. I didn't add any indexes yet.

Explain output:

```
id:1    
select_type:SIMPLE  
table:largeTable 
type:ALL    
possible_keys:NULL  
key: NULL   
key_len:NULL    
ref: NULL   
rows: 3492633   
Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

Table Structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `largeTable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(528) NOT NULL,
  `target_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4013829 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Do you have an index on your `msg` column? Or any indexes?

Comment: Missing info: output of `EXPLAIN`, output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, which engine and if InnoDB - configuration used. As usual, this is most likely an I/O problem caused by insufficient `innod_buffer_pool_size` setting. The default value is `128`mb, you should up that.

Comment: `show create table largeTable` and publish. Btw the core count is irrelevant. smp on mysql is iffy

Comment: or *consider* putting a composite index on (msg,timestamp) and ponder where that may slow down other stuff. If you already have an index on `msg` (which presumably is wide), tacking on a *thin* timestamp and ditching the other index won't be too painful

Comment: @RyanVincent related, who knows http://stackoverflow.com/a/12033130

Comment: It might not help but we aren't exactly at his keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EXPLAIN` and the `CREATE TABLE` say that you do not have an index for optimizing the `WHERE` clause.  And that happens before the `ORDER BY`.  So let's focus on indexing first.

```
ALTER TABLE largeTable
    ADD INDEX(msg);
```

However, that won't work because of two things:

```
`msg` varchar(528) NOT NULL,
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Do you need 528 characters?  If you could lower it to 255, that would work.  (Or maybe 341 for MyISAM.)

What version of MySQL are you running?  5.7 allows 528+utf8 to be indexes.  5.6 can do likewise, but you have to do some steps to make it possible.