# Creating sort index takes a long time

Tags: mariadb, sql-optimization, mariadb-10.3

I have an SQL (**MariaDB**, version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1):

```
SELECT
    v.employee_id AS id,
    REPLACE(
        FORMAT(
         COALESCE((
            SUM(COALESCE((COALESCE(v.amount, 0) / COALESCE(ash.value, a.standard, 0)), 0))
            /
            (
               SUM(COALESCE(v.worktime, 0)) 
               +
               (
                  SELECT SUM(COALESCE(t.break, 0)) 
                  + COALESCE(SUM(t.assigned_task1), 0) 
                  + COALESCE(SUM(t.assigned_task2), 0) 
                  + COALESCE(SUM(t.assigned_task3), 0) 
                  + COALESCE(SUM(t.assigned_task4), 0) 
                  + COALESCE(SUM(t.assigned_task5), 0) 
                  FROM times t 
                  WHERE t.employee_id = v.employee_id 
                  AND t.day BETWEEN '2022-02-03' AND '2022-02-03' 
               )
            ) 
         ), 0) * 100 
       , 0 
     ), ',', '') AS p_real 
FROM volumes v 
INNER JOIN activities a 
ON 
   v.activity_id = a.id 
   AND a.is_deleted = 0 
   AND a.id IN (-1, 145, 218, 227, 286) /* There are much more IDs in real SQL. */
LEFT JOIN activity_standard_histories ash 
ON ash.activity_id = a.id AND ash.created = (
    SELECT created 
    FROM activity_standard_histories 
    WHERE 
        DATE(activity_standard_histories.created) <= v.day 
        AND activity_standard_histories.activity_id = a.id 
    ORDER BY activity_standard_histories.created DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE 
    v.employee_id IN ('552','553','554','2113','2991') /* There are much more employee_ids in real SQL. */
    AND v.day BETWEEN '2022-02-03' AND '2022-02-03' 
GROUP BY v.employee_id
```

`volumes` table has 486.2Mb size and growth up all the time.

This query is performed for a very long time. What I've noticed:

1. Query `EXPLAIN`:

   [image]
2. State for this query is "Creating sort index" for a long time.

Tables indexes:

**volumes**
[image]

**activities**
[image]

**activity_standard_histories**
[image]

**times**
[image]

I've seen a lot of sources: [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208395/creating-sort-index-takes-96-of-query-time-even-without-any-order-by), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877571/mysql-creating-sort-index-performance-for-simple-frequent-query), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277022/slow-mysql-query-explain-shows-using-temporary-using-filesort), [this](https://sugarclub.sugarcrm.com/dev-club/f/questions-answers/1187/queries-getting-stuck-on-creating-sort-index-slowing-sugar-down/4816#4816) and so on. However, I'm not sure what exactly should I apply. Maybe it could be some additional complex index, but I'm not sure which one, given that each table already has certain indexes.

Comment: In your query is "There are much more IDs in real SQL."  Please define "much more", 10 more or 1000 more ?

Comment: @Luuk `a.id` count is 76 and `v.employee_id` count is 215. Those counts are very dynamic.

Comment: I would try to give those 76 or 215 id's using a query from the database, in stead of a list of numbers.

Comment: @Luuk Those ids come from POST (ie from form).

Comment: Pretty complex form, if it produces 76 id's + 215 other id's. I think that problem needs more attention than the performance of this query.