# Mysql index is not working in some queries

Tags: mysql

I have the below query in which the where condition uses edge_server column. I have defined the edge_server column as index, however the explain statement is showing that full table scan is performed without using the index, why is it so?

```
SELECT 
   SUM(`cre_kpi`.`attempts`) AS `attempts__sum`, 
   SUM(`cre_kpi`.`asr`) AS `asr__sum`, 
   SUM(`cre_kpi`.`ner`) AS `ner__sum`,
   SUM(`cre_kpi`.`cranckbackCount`) AS `cranckbackCount__sum` 
FROM `cre_kpi` 
WHERE (`cre_kpi`.`edge_server` like 'AFTEC1')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql - "Select like" not using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030028/mysql-select-like-not-using-index)

Comment: ```WHERE (`cre_kpi`.`edge_server` like 'AFTEC1')``` is the same as ```WHERE (`cre_kpi`.`edge_server` = 'AFTEC1')``` - use equiation instead of LIKE.

Comment: It would help if you would edit the question and paste the contents of the EXPLAIN rather than paraphrasing them.

Answer (score 2):

There can be many possibility, maybe it's because your data has too few distinct values, the optimizer decided a full table scan is more efficient than using index, or the index statistics are not up to date, the optimizer decided not to use the index etc.

Anyways, it's can be many reasons, you can use `EXPLAIN` statement to see how the optimizer is accessing the data and whether it's using the index: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How can I identify the exact reason why the index is not used in a query?

Comment: Did you try the ```EXPLAIN``` statement? For example ```EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a WHERE b > 1;```.

Comment: Yes I tried the explain statement, but the index is not recogniced?

Comment: The ```EXPLAIN``` statement should show you two columns ```type``` and ```Extra```. The ```type``` column has the information about the type of join being used e.g. index. And the ```Extra``` column has information about how the query is executed e.g. using temporary tables or a specific index etc.

Answer (score 1):

What percent of the table has `edge_server` like 'AFTEC1'?  (Bryce alludes to this.)  If more than about 20%, the Optimizer will decide to scan the table rather than bounce between the index's BTree and the data BTree.

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` may give clues as to *why* it picked doing a table scan.  The [*Optimizer trace*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace) goes into more detail and "cost" analysis.